# Monero Custom Genesis Block

Tags: blockchain, genesisblock

I tried to change...
//std::string const GENESIS_TX = "013c01ff0001ffffffffffff03029b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd08807121017767aafcde9be00dcfd098715ebcf7f410daebc582fda69d24a28e9d0bc890d1";
    std::string const GENESIS_TX = "021e01ff0001ffffffffffff03029b2e4c0281c0b02e7c53291a94d1d0cbff8883f8024f5142ee494ffbbd08807121017767aafcde9be00dcfd098715ebcf7f410daebc582fda69d24a28e9d0bc890d1";
I changed the version and the unlock time, but when i begin the deamon, show me this:
[image]

Any help? I need to change that to create a new genesis block...

Thank you!!

Comment: I founded a solution. I created a cryptonote genesis (you can see https://cryptonotestarter.org/inner.html) block and changed "3f" by "3c" (unlock time)...Thats all...